# Prevent users from changing column size

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet where other users in my organisation have edit access. One annoying problem we're facing is users changing the sizes of the columns.

How do I prevent users from changing the size of any column in the sheet? I am open to using Google Apps Script to implement a solution.

Comment: You can't prevent them from changing, but you can keep reseting them from time to time.

Comment: use the suggestion above. see time triggers. to help you further you need to post code and what didnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to make use of the "[On Change](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#eventsDetails)" trigger.  It detects a couple of things, one of which is if you modify a column width.  The 'changeType' will be "OTHER".

Unfortunately, there isn't an easy way to see what column was re-sized, so you'll have to just reset every column back to whatever the default is.  Additionally, this will also trigger for edits, inserting/deleting columns, etc.  So you'll have to choose to what level a user can modify the spreadsheet, and otherwise, bailout of the function:

```
function onChange(e) {
  if (e.changeType != "OTHER") {
    return;
  } else {
    //otherwise re-size columns
  }
 }
```

Also, it's an installable trigger, so you'll have to enable it.  From the script editor:

> 1. **Resources -> Current project's triggers**
> 2. Click the link for "**No triggers set up...**"
>
>    - If you already have an installed trigger, click "Add a new trigger"
> 3. Select which function to **Run** when a change is detected.
> 4. Select '**From spreadsheet**' under '**Events**'
> 5. Select '**On Change**' in the final drop-down box.

Otherwise, an installable time-based trigger is also an option, as others have suggested.